# PDO->execute() How to know what type of command was executed?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having major issues with one of my functions I am trying to work around in,

I have a query function that binds the value to placeholders and executes the PDO query. (Nothing special there)

However I have an issue in this part of the code:

```
if($this->_query->execute()){
    try{
        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }catch(Exception $e){ // Get error }
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
}else{$this->_error = TRUE;}
```

Now in the above code my issue occurs when I do an INSERT statement, and I know why as well. When I do insert / create new record I can't use fetchALL as there is nothing to be fetched. I am trying to figure out how to check before or after execute() if the command is to insert or select.

Thanks for any and all help....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467561/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-query-statement-in-pdo

Comment: How do you control this query process? Do you feed a statement into a function and execute it? Like how do you not control if it's a select delete insert query?

Comment: @Rasclatt I have functions like Update, Insert, Delete and so on.. There I create the statement like $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";.... Than I pass it to a query function where all the place folders are binded

Comment: Why can't you just pass an action as a parameter so something like: `public function ($sql, $action = 'select') { code }` Then it would know to do select explicitly or, use a query class similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446088/

Comment: Hello @IamCavic , did you ever figure this out? I am also having problems with if($this->_query->execute()){   
        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)